# Regex file extension filter

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will take all files that do not have a list of extensions.  In particular, I am trying to filter out filenames that end in .csv

I have browsed around for an hour and been unable to figure this out.  I am using .NET Regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do the trick.  I just tested it with .net.

```
^.*\.(?!csv).*$
```

Be sure to include the IgnoreCase [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this worked perfect!  Out of curiosity, why doesn't it work without the .* at the end?

Comment: The * operator says "include any number of X or none at all". In this case X is a "." so its any character. If you want to require an extension of some kind switch that "*" to a "+"

Comment: This fails when you have another period before the file extension. (eg. myFile.extension.txt)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net 3.5 or higher, this non-regex solution should work:

```
var root = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = root.GetFiles();

var filteredFiles = files.Where(f => f.Extension != "csv");
```

Comment: This is a good example, but it is actually a list of file names in a text file with no usable split string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        For Each r As String In _invalidFileExpressions
            If bValid Then
                bValid = Not Regex.IsMatch(FileName, r, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            End If
        Next
```

r would be defined as .net regular expression, some samples:

```
        ".*\.csv" 
        ".*d\.txt" 
        "\d\d_\d{8}[dmysDMYS].txt" 
        ".*(batch).*\.txt"
        ".*(elvis).*\.txt"
        ".*(anal).*\.txt"
        ".*(monthlystats)\.txt"
        ".*(rx)\.txt"
        ".*(BAD|bad)\.txt"
        ".*(mm)\.txt"
        ".*(flu)\.txt"
```